# Start with lambda functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I've done some small tests with lambda functions on AWS and it's amazing how everything works, I would like to start a project in an organize way: with a repo and a coherent structure but I don't know how to get the coherent structure, do you have any clue?

In my head, I would like to have something like a monorepo or structure with every lambda function in a folder, with all their dependencies in their packages.json or similar, having some order, do you know any scaffolding, project in order to get that? Also it would be glad some CI to deploy with "no effort".

Answer (score 2):

If you a newbie with lambda functions and overall with AWS in my mind you can try to use the serverless framework for creating mono repo with different lambdas.

https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb

my guess is the simplest way

also a lot of examples you can find here: https://serverless.com/examples/